# PhpStorm does not process functions return type

Tags: javascript, phpstorm, webstorm, jsdoc

Say I have the following code:

```
/**
 * 
 * @return {string}
 */
function f() {
    return '';
}

f().toFixed();
```

`toFixed` is not highlighted with an error of incorrect method. It only works if I do the following:

```
/** @type {string} */
var a = f();
a.toFixed();
```

Does not PhpStorm support processing return variables or do I code something wrong?

**Edit 1**:

I add a screenshoot of how I see this cose in PhpStorm:

[image]

Add I must say that PhpStorm really at first offers methods from `String#`. It is good. My concern is that does not mark `toFixed` as an error when I specify `string` type on a var. See the following image:

[image]

Comment: I would suggest creating an issue on Jetbrains' [bug tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues). I don't see any reason why the editor would behave like this. It's like it knows it's a string (at least IntelliSense does when you try to perform an autocomplete), but it also supposes it could be something else as well. Shouldn't happen when it's clearly documented on the JSDoc (and especially when it can also infer the type of the actual value being returned).

Comment: **1)** Added `webstorm` tag as it's shares the same JS code (PhpStorm = WebStorm + PHP + DB) **2)** Please show screenshots of how it looks on your computer/what does not work. When I have tried it (note: I'm not JS person) `toFixed` was not offered in code completion (was marked as unknown) in both cases but `toUpper` was present.

Comment: @LazyOne you are right. I updated the question

Comment: I see the difference. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB I would say.